# open a Twitter's Boostrap 2.x Modal on pageload with dialog2

Tags: iframe, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I know this question has been answered many times but my issue is different.

I am using a bootstrap modal extension that enables iframe's (dialog2 https://github.com/yorch/jquery-bootstrap-scripting). I am trying to load the modal on page load. it does not work using the normal method.

The page tries to load the modal, an overlay appears but no modal and when I click on the page the

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#test').modal('show');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dialog-iframe").dialog2IFrame(    {
          height:900,
          closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
          closeOnEscape: true, 
          removeOnClose: true, 
          showCloseHandle: true,

    });
        focussed:true
        });
```

HTML link

```
<a id="test" href="'.$url.'/popupviewresponse/'.$responses->response_id.'/'.seoUrl($responses->title).'" onclick="return loaded;"  class="dialog-iframe desktop-iframe" title="'.ucfirst($responses->title).'" >'.ucfirst($responses->title).'</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Which extension do you use to enable iframes in dialog2. I found one (or some code) on: [Setting iframe width via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825124/setting-iframe-width-via-javascript).</strike> i found: https://github.com/yorch/jquery-bootstrap-scripting/blob/master/lib/jquery.dialog2.iframe.js Using some of this code i could open a modal with iframe on page load, see: http://plnkr.co/kBad2fnPWsxOWvhhfYNu

```
   <button id="framedialog" href="http://www.streetart.nl/">Open</button>
```

This button holds the the url you want to load in the iframe in the href attribute.

Load the iframe, hide the button and open the dialog with a click:

```
 $('#framedialog').hide().dialog2IFrame();
 $('#framedialog').hide().trigger('click');
```

The modified extension:

```
/*  
* jQuery Dialog2 IFrame
* 
* Licensed under the MIT license 
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php 
* 
* @version: 0.0.1 (09/06/2013)
* 
* @requires jQuery >= 1.4 
* 
* @requires jQuery.dialog2 plugin >= 1.1
* 
* @modified by Bass Jobsen (bass@w3masters.nl)
* @original author Jorge Barnaby (jorge.barnaby {at} gmail.com)
*/
(function ($) {

    /*
    * Shows a web page (using iframe) in a jQuery dialog2 (Bootstrap style).
    *
    */
    $.fn.dialog2IFrame = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.dialog2IFrame.defaults, options);
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var idDialogOuter = "dialog-iframe-outer";
            var $dialogOuter = $('#' + idDialogOuter).length ?
                $('#' + idDialogOuter) :
                $('<div id="' + idDialogOuter + '"></div>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
            var $dialogFrame = $('iframe', $dialogOuter).length ?
                $('iframe', dialogOuter) :
                $('<iframe frameborder="0" />').appendTo($dialogOuter);


            // Adds URL to iframe src
            $dialogFrame.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));

            $dialogOuter.css('overflow', 'hidden').css('padding', '0').css('margin', '0');

            $dialogOuter.dialog2(
            {
                autoOpen: true,
                closeOnOverlayClick: options.closeOnOverlayClick,
                closeOnEscape: options.closeOnEscape,
                removeOnClose: true,
                showCloseHandle: options.showCloseHandle,
                initialLoadText: "Loading..."
            });

            var $dialog = $dialogOuter.parent();

            $dialog.addClass(options.additionalClass);

            // Removes footer if empty
            $footer = $dialog.find('.modal-footer');
            //console.log($footer.text().length);
            if ($footer.text().length == 0) {
                $footer.remove();
            }

            // Sets the iframe width and height to the same as the modal (must be done at the end)
            $dialogFrame.width($dialogOuter.width()).height($dialogOuter.height());
        });
    }

    $.fn.dialog2IFrame.defaults = {
        height: "900",
        additionalClass: "",
        // Appends &iframe=true to URL opened on IFrame
        appendParamUrl: false,
        // Reloads main page when modal is closed
        reloadOnClose: false,
        closeOnOverlayClick: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        showCloseHandle: false,
        close: function () {
            return true;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```